# Cannot upload image file using retrofit2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-upload, retrofit2

Problem with old code, image sending to server is thumbnail image (so small). So with new code, Android has changed the way to get real size image. However, new code not working upload file to the server. It says filename is empty and when I do log body request not the same result as the old code. Any help, I really appreciate because almost one week I still couldn't found what is the problem with the new code.

```
///////// This is old cold//////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                break;
            }
            case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
                    if (typePhoto.equals("ftCarLol")) {
                        carLoL = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                System.currentTimeMillis() + "ftLol.png");

                        FileOutputStream fo = null;

                        try {
                            carLoL.createNewFile();
                            fo = new FileOutputStream(carLoL);
                            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                            fo.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ftCar.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    }

                    if (typePhoto.equals("sdcarLol")) {
                        sdCad = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                System.currentTimeMillis() + "sdCars.png");

                        FileOutputStream fo = null;

                        try {
                            sdCad.createNewFile();
                            fo = new FileOutputStream(sdCad);
                            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                            fo.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        sdCar.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    }

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// in retrofit
MultipartBody.Part[] imageUserList = new MultipartBody.Part[2];
RequestBody propertyImage = null;for(
int i = 0;i<2;i++)
{
    if (i == 0) {
        propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), carLoL);
        imageUserList[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("car", carLoL.getName(), propertyImage);
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), sdCad);
        imageUserList[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sd", sdCad.getName(), propertyImage);
    }
}
// Call function interface retrofit
Call<JsonObject> clientreq = client.submitReport(imageUserList);

// interface retrofit
@Multipart
@POST("TestReport")
Call<JsonObject>submitReport(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] files);

/////////////////////// new code////////////////////////////////////
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp.png");
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "cntsb.com.rodeo.fileprovider", tempFile);

// result activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (typeChoose.equals("sdcarLol")) {
            sdCad = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() +"sdCars.png");
            try {
                sdCad.createNewFile();
                if(tempFile.renameTo(sdCad)) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(sdCad).into(sdCar);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (typeChoose.equals("ftCarLol")){
            carLoL = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + "ftLol.png");

            try {
                carLoL.createNewFile();
                if(tempFile.renameTo(carLoL)) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(carLoL).into(ftCar);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// attach file into retrofit
MultipartBody.Part[] imageUserList = new MultipartBody.Part[2];
RequestBody propertyImage = null;for(
int i = 0;i<2;i++)
{
    if (i == 0) {
        propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), carLoL);
        imageUserList[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("car", carLoL.getName(), propertyImage);
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), sdCad);
        imageUserList[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sd", sdCad.getName(), propertyImage);
    }
}
// Call function interface retrofit
Call<JsonObject> clientreq = client.submitReport(imageUserList);
```

Expected result: after log request body

```
�PNG

    ������IHDR��������������������}��������s��O����� ��IDATx�\�k�d�q%�wĹ7���h4��B$%R�F������|�G�k��g$��z-{F=H�C
    $�@t��g>�9��f������2o�s"b��;��/�o�&�Hp��)��4�l��gs��    �   ��I@FdN�'l9�ۭ���    ��  ejb�H�q��,��':Jw�D)`�4�"ő   3#9��Lg���d LF���f:߸5O��L�bhn��HN�$) !�$�dDЍ�� -F���e0E)��  ��[r$DP���6�    �����߼T��4���1�`��+4�$M���%s�sR�L�� ��B�D2�������$Ѥ$������RRԚ.cDv����[(3����R�Df�9:"a23R!����"!)��BL�dfRQ[��C��jl����{}�e9�
    e�0���s(d�T��H)QR(���H@fX����)���Hm2(Aa�C��$��i6��"�%q������LfI(�F���Zf�$
    �d2If�0���Y�LF����`��D$pGI����(364��6�eO���@dD$֣�Ӻ�0�$IA����[I!���'LI��9�@i֤>ƨ?���0��ʡ��&��4$��DMn�.�ǉH���IR��
    4   �9���PH��ƒ@D�4��͐��@�Y��]Rf���1s��  $�"I�� ��c����7)3��f���xR�C)i$���U�X�}u�ZSw�il��H��`��吹�:��mM +����m�z���S(�XX'֜Z�f�3@!�)I�"�@��ެ>�c���i�����E��S��d(33"�9���tw%ͽ��H2I�9J)�C���$Ț�2�L$��ȔxX��K
    �<7��4�S��H&epI�j�Բ�1z��L���b����\c��`��\?�H�jM�0�  R@ ��|<Q�   QI���6ײ$է����j�"S�,��?u���D���zI8��f����ˈTD�ߎr��_=�`��3��H��˼2���I!����5nͥ�+�Y�uְnF=���~`�B��״�`մ�����̬MDssw�%2s�NfBf(qJ
   ID�2S\�HV�!����R�Z��Hef�H�8��z�ua���4��:H�Q{��t�Uj�I1���_V����@!AEJ
    [��CffHO������jwk�!���5�CT؀��E���,c�/���:��rN��`����@B���<������ʢ���썭��YYE�)V��9�R6�f��4�$  dB0�U3SF��f�����X���FV
    ��1tJ5\��tk���VxT�S��������&V4��I�H4d��LO���.h*#�))���M-s���&@33���$d3I$�m=�`m�d�/��{�`)���
    =��F���L3�H$��4��gIt��Ar@f03�G�q%Y�N@~ʼv�1�̯���I2��HZq2m�me��!i2.�RI�S$h(�5��R�����5���wP�ҪC8�^>��S�]SY�##��i�TbG�g2bT:�F Ɍ��&o�H`>��pnI�Ԛ(��
    4dk�"N�i$�4{%h"Sn�Ќ��D�ZkUN��{���z�@����4k
    dB��[Y(C��I��if ������tx%n���kMO�I��Lr�(�=�ehHLA9F0*��V(\�����2S^�B��$�.)B�QHiD׊�(�*kם�4M����H�9�fNfV+r
    ���(�16�R���.<ǪRF�,�d$92��aP��.#����ښ"ift0:�)�ܽ���G�&�(d_�H+df���j�)��7���$Vk���(#9MS5v�d�zP��  ��BdJ�1����D���ٚ�����z�2�@��c��UxQh6R˲��N�iE�nS��s��Tݵ��@DdF��C'��D�<��$��܎J0��׏��^ߨ�s��ڒ��C�bD�y������I��֚Y�@��   ���������"  @LU!Y����53W�!L2m����U�Y��(xM2�R�A�jg�v*���6W:�r��jX$�6RZѝ5�t��)��<G��BM(Y����y��7��c���2N��R�1WT`�٦*�IV�è����D�Ĝ���2��^    �8U�GkE�$��N8
    (���hk/�#��3�nS�5�g��r<���ՙ����0�<���}D�,�Wi@�P�t�$ִ����0"j����D��
```

error from new code:

```
����A2Exif����MM��*�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������(��������������1���������������2������������������������������i����������������!8HUAWEI����DUK-L09��������H������������H������DUK-L09 9.0.1.176(C636E2R1P5)�����2019:07:04 10:46:13����.��������������������������������P�������������� ʈ"���������������'������������������������0210������������� ڐ������������ ������������������������ ��
    ����������X������������� Ғ��
    ����������@���
    ����������H������������� �������������������������������    ���������������
    ������������0�|��������d���� N�|����������� ��|��������/�������|�����������`�|������������ H��������������!��������������!
    ��������������!�����������0100��������������������������������������������������������!�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������8������������������������������������������������������������������ �����������������
    ����������������������������������������������������������d������d����������������������������
    ����;������������'#*#*201709272016::76������/��`����������DLBB8�}N�������������������::76������/��`����������DLBB8�}N�������������������::76������/��`����������DLBB8�}N�������������������::54������/��`�����@����AIBB8�wN�������������������::54����/����`�����@����AIBB8�wN�������������������::54����/����`�����@����AIBB8�wN�������������������::2����.����`�����@����=EBB8�rN�������������������::0/������-��`�����@����:CBB8�oN��������������������� ��4����B������������������������������������������275��h����� ��+����j^SJC>93+$m_TKD?:4,%o`ULE?:4-%qbVME?:5.&sdWMF@;7/' ueXMFA=70( vfXNGA=81)!vfYNGB=81)"ufYOGB>92*"teZOHB>:3+#tfZPIC>:4+$tfZQIC>:4,$sfZRJD>:4,%qdZRJD?:4-%odZQJD?:5-&mcYQJD?:5.&������������������������������������������������������������������������������������:�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������J���@�������������������������������������������x�� �������F��F���������������������������������������   ����������������������*������:����������������������*������:������(��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

Comment: perhaps your file name is empty?

Comment: @JohnJoe nope because i use glide function appear that image from file that I will send to the server.

Comment: where is your glide fuction?

Comment: @JohnJoe .   if(tempFile.renameTo(sdCad)) {
                    Glide.with(context).load(sdCad).into(sdCar);
                }